# Powermock private stubbing gows wrong

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock, powermockito

Im trying to make a simple as a can example which could be found on official PowerMock's page ([here](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage#partial-mocking)).I' doing a partial mock of this class :

```
public class Simple {


    public String doMe() {
        return privateMethod();
    }

    private String privateMethod() {
       return "POWERMOCK sucks";

    }

}
```

And wrote a simple test class :

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Simple.class)
public class ProcessorTest  {

    @Test
    public void doMe() throws Exception {
        Simple spy = PowerMockito.spy(new Simple());
        PowerMockito.doReturn("hello").when(spy, "privateMethod");
        String res = spy.doMe();

        PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(spy, Mockito.times(1000)).invoke(
                "privateMethod");
        Assert.assertEquals( res, "hello");
    }


}
```

But result is like this :

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [hello] but found [null]
Expected :hello
Actual   :null
 <Click to see difference>


    at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)
```

So Powermock not only fails to mock the `privateMethod` and return 'null' it's OK with that it was called 1000 times when it was not.

It get even more creepy if I try to mess with mocking like this :

```
PowerMockito.doReturn(1).when(spy, "privateMethod");
```

So I'm trying to return an Integer instead of String from the `privateMethod`.
Then I get this :

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
Integer cannot be returned by doMe()
doMe() should return String
***
```

So by some reason Powermock is trying to mock public `doMe` method.

Any one understands what is happining? I dont.

Thanks.

My environment is :

Java 1.8, Mockito 1.10.19, Powermock 1.6.2

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue by using your code snippet. Please, see my example on [Github](https://github.com/thekingnothing/stackoverflow/tree/master/q36086167)

Comment: which configuration do you have?

Comment: I use: JDK "1.8.0_74" for MacOS and all other libs has same version as you. You may check it on Github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found solution, the problem was that JUnit's `@RunWith` did not actually do the trick so I had to extend from `PowerMockTestCase` to make it work. The test looks like this now and it works like a charm:

```
@PrepareForTest(Simple.class)
public class ProcessorTest extends PowerMockTestCase {
    @Test
    public void doMe() throws Exception {
        Simple spy = PowerMockito.spy(new Simple());
        PowerMockito.doReturn("hello").when(spy, "privateMethod");

        String res = spy.doMe();

        PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(spy, Mockito.times(1)).invoke(
                "privateMethod");
        Assert.assertEquals( res, "hello");
    }
}
```